# Javascript failing because the dom has been altered?

Tags: javascript, dom

These two javascript functions work perfectly on unaltered dom elements. However the delete_route function fails when asked to delete elements appended to the dom via the second function. For clarity, I am only looking at elements where `parts[0]` is always option - it is created by spliting the a > id on the "_".

Why is Javascript apparently seeing this difference between "native" dom objects and inserted objects?

```
//handle delete events
function delete_route (parts) {
  if (parts[0] == "field") {

    var select_container = "container_"+parts[2];
    var getContainer = document.getElementById(select_container);

   getContainer.parentNode.removeChild(getContainer);

  } else if (parts[0] == "option") {
    var optionId = parts[0]+"_"+parts[2]+"_"+parts[3];
    var getOption = document.getElementById(optionId);

   getOption.parentNode.removeChild(getOption);
  }
}

//handle new events
function new_route (parts) {
   var highest_number = -1;

  if (parts[0] == "field") {
  } else if (parts[0] == "option") {
    var selectContainer = "container_"+parts[2];
    var thisContainer = document.getElementById(selectContainer);

    //get last option id (for new object tagging)
    var optionList = thisContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var optionListLength = optionList.length -2;

    //more accurate new node placement than last option which didn't work correctly anyway
    lastChild = "options_wrapper_"+parts[2];
    var lastChildNode = document.getElementById(lastChild);

     //generate option
    var labelNode = document.createElement ("label");
    var inputNode = document.createElement ("input");
    var linkNode  = document.createElement ("a");
    var breakNode = document.createElement ("br");

    inputNode.setAttribute("type", "text");
    var inputNodeId = parts[0]+"_"+parts[2]+"_"+optionListLength;
    inputNode.setAttribute("id", inputNodeId);
    inputNode.setAttribute("name", inputNodeId);
    inputNode.setAttribute("value", "Undefined");

    labelNode.setAttribute ("for", inputNodeId);
    var labelNodeText = document.createTextNode ("Option Value");

    linkNode.setAttribute("href", "#");
    var linkId = parts[0]+"_delete_"+parts[2]+"_"+optionListLength;
    linkNode.setAttribute("id", linkId);
    var linkNodeText = document.createTextNode ("Delete option");

    lastChildNode.appendChild (labelNode);
    labelNode.appendChild (labelNodeText);
    lastChildNode.appendChild (inputNode);
    lastChildNode.appendChild (linkNode);
    linkNode.appendChild (linkNodeText);
    lastChildNode.appendChild (breakNode);

  }
}
```

HTML this applies to (I have gone though some effort with the creating part - options that were inserted by javascript are exactly indentical to "native" page elements):

```
         <div id="options_wrapper_7">
    <label for="option_7_0">Option Value</label><input type=text id="option_7_0" name="option_7_0" value="Red"> <a id="option_delete_7_0" href="#">Delete option</a><br>

<label for="option_7_1">Option Value</label><input type=text id="option_7_1" name="option_7_1" value="Green"><a id="option_delete_7_1" href="#">Delete option</a><br>

<label for="option_7_2">Option Value</label><input type=text id="option_7_2" name="option_7_2" value="Blue"><a id="option_delete_7_2" href="#">Delete option</a><br>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the code from your previous questions, you're assigning event handlers at `window.onload` by calling the `clickDetection()` function.

I assume when you've created new elements, you haven't bothered to give those new elements the same event handlers that your initial `clickDetection()` does.

If that's the case, you'll need to be sure that those new elements get handlers that can respond to clicks.

```
   // make a separate reference to the handler so we can use it
   //    for elements that are created later.
function clickHandler() {
    clickRoute(this);
    return false
};

function clickDetection() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("content");
    var dumbLinks = canvas.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for (var i = 0; i < dumbLinks.length; i++) {
             // Assign the "clickHandler" when the page loads
        dumbLinks[i].onclick = clickHandler; 
    }
}
```

Then in your `new_route` function, manually assign `clickHandler` to the new `<a>` element.

```
function new_route (parts) {
   var highest_number = -1;

  if (parts[0] == "field") {
  } else if (parts[0] == "option") {
    var selectContainer = "container_"+parts[2];
    var thisContainer = document.getElementById(selectContainer);

    //get last option id (for new object tagging)
    var optionList = thisContainer.getElementsByTagName("input");
    var optionListLength = optionList.length -2;

    //more accurate new node placement than last option which didn't work correctly anyway
    lastChild = "options_wrapper_"+parts[2];
    var lastChildNode = document.getElementById(lastChild);

     //generate option
    var labelNode = document.createElement ("label");
    var inputNode = document.createElement ("input");
    var linkNode  = document.createElement ("a");
    var breakNode = document.createElement ("br");

       // ********RIGHT HERE*********
       // Assign the handler to the new "linkNode" element
    linkNode.onclick = clickHandler;

   // ...and so on with the rest of the code...

}
```

Comment: so call that function after inserting the new elements? Will try anyway, but just got called away!

Comment: @YsoL8: No, that would re-assign  the handlers to the previous elements. I'll update my answer with a solution that will let you assign the handler as you create the element.

Comment: Hi Patrick. I keep getting caught by behaviour I don't expect! Could you let me know how the clickHandler can work without explictly passing the parts variable to it? I like to have 100% understanding of the code I'm using for bug fixing down the road.

Comment: @YsoL8: What the handler does is it calls the `clickRoute()` function, and passes `this` as the argument. In a handler, `this` refers to the element that was clicked. Then in the `clickRoute()` function, it gets the ID from the element, and splits it on the `_` character. `var linkParts = linkId.split("_");` This is where your `parts` is coming from. It expects the item at index `[1]` to have either `"new"` or `"delete"`, and it calls the proper function.